# Drag and Drop data in PDF form field

Tags: pdf

I have a project that requires the user to fill out a pdf form. I am loading the pdf file into an object tag. On the side I have a list of predetermined values. I would like to enable the user to drag one of those values to a field in the form and drop it there.

I can have them right-click the value, copy it and then right-click and paste in the field, but I would like to create something a little more user friendly.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can find (I was just searching if this was possible as well), and what I know from building forms in Adobe's form builder, this is sadly no possible.